# Uploading images using forms in Django

Tags: python, django

I need help. Learning Django at the moment. Doing a simple (for now) project which is basically a site about film photocameras: it contains information, relations between cameras and films... You get the idea.

I have created two forms to create a new entry for camera and for film. Here is the models to start with:

```
class Camera(models.Model):
    ref_to_topic=models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_to_brand=models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    camera_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    camera_info=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    camera_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='site_media/camera_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    when_appeared_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    when_appeared_year=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    when_disappeared=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    when_disappeared_year=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    when_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    when_updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural='cameras'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.camera_name} - {self.camera_info[:25]}"


class Film(models.Model):
    ref_to_topic=models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_to_brand=models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    film_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    film_info=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    film_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='site_media/film_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    when_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    when_updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural='films'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.film_name} - {self.film_info[:25]}"
```

And here is the forms to full this models using browser:

```
class CameraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Camera
        fields = ['camera_name', 'camera_info', 'when_appeared_date', 'when_appeared_year', 'when_disappeared', 'when_disappeared_year', 'ref_to_topic', 'ref_to_brand', 'owner', 'camera_image']
        labels = {
            'camera_name': 'Camera',
            'camera_info': 'Info',
            'when_appeared_date': 'Started on the market (exact date, can be null)',
            'when_appeared_year': 'Strarted on the market (exact year, can be null)',
            'when_disappeared': 'When the sales stopped (exact date, can be null)',
            'when_disappeared_year': 'When the sales stopped (exact year, can be null)',
            'ref_to_topic': 'refered to topic',
            'ref_to_brand': 'refered to brand',
            'owner': 'Owner',
            'camera_image': 'Image'
        }
        widgets = {
            'camera_info': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})
        }

class FilmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ['film_name', 'film_info', 'ref_to_topic', 'ref_to_brand', 'owner', 'film_image']
        labels = {
            'film_name': 'Film',
            'film_info': 'Info',
            'ref_to_topic': 'refered to topic',
            'ref_to_brand': 'refered to brand',
            'owner': 'Owner',
            'film_image': 'Image'
        }
        widgets = {
            'film_info': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})
        }
```

Views for processing the data (for camera entry):

```
@login_required
def add_new_camera(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = CameraForm()
    else:
        form = CameraForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('content_app:cameras')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render (request, 'content_app/add_new_camera.html', context)
```

So, the problem is that when I use this forms via browser and append my image to the form and then press save, it doesn't save anything. But appending an image using Admin Panel works fine. Here is my template for adding the camera entry:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>add new camera</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends 'content_app/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>New camera:</p>
<form action="{% url 'content_app:add_new_camera' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button name="submit">add</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}  
</body>
</html>
```

And here is how it looks in browser:

[image]

When I press add: it creates new entry, but without an image attached.

I know, that I can upload images using seperate form and writing a seperate view for this, but I would like to see it works in one form. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the [request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form as well.

Try

```
CameraForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

More details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form).